# Is it possible to create an empty csv file in Django database?

Tags: python, django, csv

I am wondering if it is possible to create an empty csv file in Django database. Basically what I am trying to do is to allow the user to upload a text file as TextUpload model object, then run the code in the backend to process the text file and to save it as ProcessedTextToCsv model object. My views.py code looks something like this:

```
def upload_view(request):
    form = TextUploadsModelform(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = TextUploadsModelform()

        ProcessedTextToCsv().save()
```

I am wondering if here I can create an empty csv so I can use file_name.path as argument in the function below

```
    processTextToCsv(TextUploads.objects.latest('uploaded').file_name.path,ProcessedTextToCsv.objects.latest('uploaded').file_name.path)    
    return render(request, 'main_app/example.html',{'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as Django database. Django is a framework that uses several databases.

Back to your question, yes it is possible, all steps are described in the Django tutorial for [basic-file-uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads), what you want is something similar to this:

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UploadFileForm

# Imaginary function to handle an uploaded file.
from somewhere import handle_uploaded_file

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

"somewhere".py:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open(f, 'r') as file:
        # read lines
    # Treat the data to CSV format
    with open("/path/to/your/file.csv",'w') as outfile:
        # write your data
```